# Does Facebook require a website/app to remove a users info if they delete their app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Is it required by Facebook that if a user deletes your app from their account settings, that you must remove their account/data from your database? Or if a user deletes their Facebook account you must delete their account from your database as well...I have heard this before, but can't find anything in Facebook's documentation that explicitly states this.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from Facebook's [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

> You will delete all data you receive from us concerning a user if the *user asks you to do so*, and will provide an easily accessible mechanism for users to make such a request. We may require you to delete data you receive from the Facebook API if you violate our terms.

Also, from Facebook's Help about [App Basics](http://www.facebook.com/help/100536210040498/)

> **Does deleting an app from my timeline mean that the developers no longer have access to my information?**
>  **No**. [Deleting an app](http://www.facebook.com/help/170585223002660) from your timeline simply means that it will no longer have access to any new information that you share. If you would like a developer to permanently delete all of your information, you will need to [contact the developer directly](http://www.facebook.com/help/149151751822041).

So deriving from above two information we can say that it is up to you to either delete or not delete the User's data if the User has unauthorized or deleted your app but you should delete it when asked to delete the data by the User **explicitly**.

Also, there is no policy over the deletion of User's data on deactivation of the account and it is up to you to either delete it or not, but I would suggest in keeping as Facebook  itself preserves all the User's data so that he may have his data intact when he reactivates.